# Soldering the AUX IN cable to the JVC KD-161 radio

Tags: radio

I soldered the AUX IN cable as in the diagram, added capacitors. In the diagram, pin 4 is GND. I insert a CD with a silent recording and unfortunately nothing comes from the smartphone. I will add that I am a complete amateur in these matters. The soldering went quite smoothly, no cables touching or soldering. I read threads somewhere that in a similar radio they cut off the beams from the CD stereo, but how to do it (link to the thread below) and then solder R and L. I also tried without capacitors.

[DIY Aux In connection to car stereo JVC KD-G151](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/420007/diy-aux-in-connection-to-car-stereo-jvc-kd-g151)

Here is manual to my radio:

https://www.opweb.de/english/company/JVC/KD-G162

[image]

Please let me know what I should do.

Comment: Just to clarify: the goal of what you're doing is to add an AUX-IN function to your car stereo by "overriding" the audio it would normally be playing from its internal CD player?

Comment: If that's the case, you need to find the schematic (not just the PCB layout). for your stereo, not some other stereo.

Comment: Yes, schematic is in the second link.

Comment: No it isn't. That's just a User Manual.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Here it is: https://www.opweb.de/english/company/JVC/KD-G162